# AMPscript giving error when trying to display firstname lastname

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to display `firstname` and `lastname` of patient under one doctor if field `Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c` is `null`.  First I'm trying to pass subscriber key (`Id`) to `@Idd` which is in `Acc` DE, then do lookup on `Account_Salesforce` DE to the fetch `firstname`, `lastname`.  There can be multiple patients under one doctor, so my objective is to retrieve patients full name where there `Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c` is null/

The error I am receiving is

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again. An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement. ClientID: 514001327 JobID: 0 EmailID: 0 Index: 2984 Statement: if @rowCount > 0 then for @i = 1 to @rowCount do var @firstName, @emailAddress, @rank @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__cc set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */ set @rank = field(@row,"Id") set @firstName = field(@row,"FirstName") set @emailAddress = field(@row,"LastName") set @Date_FX"

The code:

```ampscript
%%[ 

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @region, @i , @Id, @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c , @Idd , @firstName, @lastName, @rank , @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__cc

set @Id = AttributeValue("Doctor__c") 
set @Idd = AttributeValue("Id") 
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */ 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Acc", @numRowsToReturn, "Id desc, Name asc", "Id", @Idd) 
set @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c = Lookup("Account_Salesforce", "Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c", "Id" , @Idd) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

  set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */ 
  set @rank = field(@row,"Id") 
  set @firstName = field(@row,"FirstName") 
  set @lastName = field(@row,"LastName")

]%% 

%%[ next @i ]%% 

%%[ else ]%% 

  No rows found 

%%[ endif ]%%

IF EMPTY(@Date_FX_Plan_Approved__cc) THEN
  SET @ln = @lastName
  SET @fn = @firstName
ELSE
  SET @ln = @lastName 
  SET @fn = @firstname
ENDIF

]%%
%%=v(@ln)=%%, %%=v(@fn)=%%
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using try catch block on a cloud page? Also, is there any other block of ampscript above this?

Comment: Hi Swati, I am doing workaround for this since it  is still giving error, I am using sql to store all patients records in DE where there Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c is null and using same ampscript on this DE, I have nt used catch block as you mentioned, its not in cloudpage but its in email, i have updated my ampscript looks like above one is not correctlyt pasted.only if i remove IF EMPTY it works, nto sure whats wrong in that IF EMPTY

Comment: You have an extra endif on line16

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues with your loop and conditionals as [**@Swati**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/77004/swati-mishra) suggested.  I suggest taking the time to indent your code.  There's a missing `if-then` checking your row count.  Not sure your intent with the `if empty(@Date_FX_Plan_Approved_cc) then` conditional.  You're not setting `@Date_FX_Plan_Approved_cc` anywhere that I can see.  Additionally, both the `then` and `else` are assigning the same values.

Perhaps you can update your question to provide some sample data from your sending Data Extension (including `Doctor_cc` and `id`), `Acc` and `Account_Salesforce`, and the desired output.

I've added some debugging output to help validate your conditionals:

```ampscript
%%[ 

set @debug = 1 /* set to zero to disable debugging output */

set @Id = AttributeValue("Doctor__c") 
set @Idd = AttributeValue("Id") 
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */ 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Acc", @numRowsToReturn, "Id desc, Name asc", "Id", @Idd) 
set @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c = Lookup("Account_Salesforce", "Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c", "Id" , @Idd) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

if @debug = 1
  output(concat("<br>id: ", @id))
  output(concat("<br>Idd: ", @Idd))
  output(concat("<br>Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c: ", @Date_FX_Plan_Approved__c))
  output(concat("<br>rowCount: ", @rowCount))
endif

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */ 
    set @firstName = field(@row,"FirstName") 
    set @lastName = field(@row,"LastName")

    IF EMPTY(@Date_FX_Plan_Approved__cc) THEN
      SET @ln = @lastName
      SET @fn = @firstName
    ELSE
      SET @ln = @lastName 
      SET @fn = @firstname
    ENDIF  

    output(concat("<br>ln: ", @ln))
    output(concat("<br>fn: ", @fn))
 
  next @i

else 

  output(concat("<br>No rows found"))

endif 

]%%
```